# PhoneGap get value in query string

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I working on a WP7 PhoneGap prj and I trying to get the value in query string but I can't do it.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What code have you tried so far?
And are you using C# or VB.NET?

Here's a basic c# example:

```
textbox1.text = string.format("Value: {0}",NavigationContext.QueryString.(["id"], out id);
```

Comment: I don't have c# on my prj I have just html pages

Answer (score 3):

There is no support of querystring in web application using phonegap for windows phone 7.

However we can replace ? with # or anything else to pass the data like convert

```
Sample.html?id=12312
```

to

```
Sample.html#id=12312
```